# Getting stdout pointer in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, msvcrt

I want to call c function 'fputc', so that I need FILE pointer (in my case it's stdout). I know that I can use putc equivalent, but I'm curious if it is even possible to get pointer to stdout in asm. In c or c++ I would write something like 'stdout' or '&_iob[1]'. Is it even possible to get this working without replacing 'fputc' with 'putc'? (Target architecture is Windows on x86-32).

Example code (I want to print 'A'):

```
    push <the value I need>
    push 0x41
    call _fputc
    add esp, 8
```

Comment: What operating system and architecture are you programming for?

Comment: `fdopen(STDOUT_FILENO, "r")`. Ouch, you need Windows solution, no idea then

Comment: I use msvcrt so it is windows

Comment: @qwertyuiqwertyui Are you writing a 16 bit, a 32 bit, or a 64 bit program?  It looks like x86, but I really don't like having to guess.

Comment: 32 bit program.

Comment: @qwertyuiqwertyui Please add these details to your question.  Be sure to mention x86, too.  Also, remove the C++ tag as there doesn't seem to be anything about C++ in your question.

Comment: If you have the stdlib linked, you should just be able to use the `stdout` symbol

Comment: @Artyer If there is such a symbol, that is.  I'm not super familiar with MSVCRT, but it is likely that `stdin` is a macro expanding to something like `&_iob[1]` as OP hinted.  In this case, the address must be computed from the size of a file file structure plus the `_iob` symbol.

Comment: Last time I had this question, I searched for an answer for a while before just trying the symbol `stdout`, which worked. YMMV depending on the implementation of your C library.

Comment: @qwertyuiqwertyui: you usually don't have to open stdout yourself; ISO C's `FILE *stdout` should exist as a static symbol you can load the pointer value from.  CRT is responsible for initializing it.  Unless it's only a macro in MSVC's CRT?  If it's a real pointer variable, the asm name should be `_stdout`  So `push  dword ptr [_stdout]` should work.

Comment: I think stdout just calls the OS to do putc (ah=2,dh=0,dl=char,int 21h) am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You call __iob_func from MSVCRT.dll, it returns the iob struct and you add 0x30 to it and that's the address for stdout.